# How can I create a block to register a user as a specific role?

Tags: 7, forms, users

I would like to have a block that would display the standard user registration form but will register the user to a specific role (i.e. "Customer").

I'm thinking about making a block and using some php to get the form I need, display it, and add on the user's role before it is submitted.

I've been tinkering for a little and can't seem to accomplish this. Could anyone help me out with the php I would need to do this?

Thanks

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole is still in development for D7, but you might be able to pull some code out for your use...